# Finding abnormally high values in a list with Hadoop / Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I got stuck on some homework for days, and decided to ask StackOverflow's help.
I have a big CSV file containing a list of people, their role and salary.

Some salaries have been artificially inflated, and I need to find them.
Here is a sample screenshot of the file.
[image: Screenshot]

I guess the way to do this is to define an area where the salaries are considered "normals" for each role.
How can i do this ? I don't study statistics, I don't know if I should use standard deviation to define the middle value for each role...

What would you do ?

My CSV file is available through Hive, on a Hadoop cluster (Cloudera QuickStart VM).
I can use the language I want to solve this problem.

This is the first time I work on Hadoop and Hive. I only know web languages such as JS / PHP, so I'm very unfamiliar with this kind of problems.

Comment: believe me or not but in Hive you also need to know should you use standard deviation or not, or something else

Comment: What does that mean ? I don't want to compute it, I just want to have the extreme values !